# XSLT: Trying to combine two nodes based on the value of an element of those two nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, kml

I am struggling with XSLT and have been for days.  I'm in the process of modifying a previous coworkers python code that transforms many different JSON files into xml and finally into kml.  I'm within a hairs breadth of wrapping this up and, of course, the one part I can't get my head around is what's left.

I have an xml file with this structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <document xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
        <group>
            <display_name>Housing</display_name>
            <id>Housing</id>
            <item>
                <id>5063</id>
                <image_url>images/5063.jpg</image_url>
                <latitude>40.354007</latitude>
                <longitude>-74.666675</longitude>
                <name>Stanworth Apartments</name>
            </item>
         .
         . (Many items omitted)
         .
    </group>
    <group>
        <display_name>Buildings</display_name>
        <id>Building</id>
        <item>
            <id>5025</id>
            <image_url>images/5025.jpg</image_url>
            <latitude>40.350066</latitude>
            <longitude>-74.603464</longitude>
            <name>Lyman Spitzer Building</name>
            <name_alt>LSB</name_alt>
            <organization_id>ORG418</organization_id>
        </item>
         .
         . (Many items omitted)
         .
    </group>
    <group>
         .
         . (Many groups omitted)
         .
    </group>
    <group>
        <display_name>Accessible Features</display_name>
        <id>Entryway</id>
        <item>
            <description>Accessible entryway</description>
            <id>E028</id>
            <latitude>40.349159</latitude>
            <longitude>-74.658629</longitude>
            <name>E028</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <description>Accessible entryway</description>
            <id>E029</id>
            <latitude>40.349398</latitude>
            <longitude>-74.658517</longitude>
            <name>E029</name>
        </item>
    </group>
    <group>
        <display_name>Accessible Features</display_name>
        <id>Route</id>
        <item>
            <description>Accessible pathway</description>
            <id>R054</id>
            <name>R054</name>
            <steps>-74.66032495749012,40.3489269473544</steps>
            <steps>-74.6602836233495,40.34888813533125</steps>
        </item>
        <item>
            <description>Accessible pathway</description>
            <id>R055</id>
            <name>R055</name>
            <steps>-74.66023036637355,40.34884827131961</steps>
            <steps>-74.66018651597699,40.34881015960344</steps>
        </item>
        <item>
            <description>Accessible pathway</description>
            <id>R072</id>
            <name>R072</name>
            <steps>-74.66101885775542,40.34737535360176</steps>
            <steps>-74.6610915120654,40.34740600913134</steps>
            <steps>-74.66187000551304,40.34717392492537</steps>
        </item>
   </group>
</document>
```

Each "group" is transformed into a Folder in the final KML file.

```
<Folder id="Housing">
    <name>Housing</name>
    <Placemark id="_0288">
          .
          . (Many lines omitted)
          .
```

The goal is to create one Folder "id='Accessible" with the contents of two groups.  The group with id='Entryway' and the group with id='Route.  The desired output would be:

```
<Folder id="Accessible">
    <name>Accessible Features</name>
    <Placemark id="_E001">
        <name>E001</name>
        <description><![CDATA[<div><p>Accessible entryway</p></div>]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#entryway</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-74.663266, 40.348289,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark id="_E002">
        <name>E002</name>
        <description><![CDATA[<div><p>Accessible entryway</p></div>]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#entryway</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-74.662252, 40.348057,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
      .
      . then have the items from the group with id='Route'
      .
     <Placemark id="_R002">
        <name>Accessible Routes</name>
        <description><![CDATA[<div><p>Accessible pathway</p></div>]]></description>
        <styleUrl/>
        <Style>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>FFFF0000</color>
                <width>4</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>
                      -74.65135187837255,40.34699608960065
                      -74.65134698312161,40.34698651192196
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
     <Placemark id="_R003">
        <name>Accessible Routes</name>
        <description><![CDATA[<div><p>Accessible pathway</p></div>]]></description>
        <styleUrl/>
        <Style>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>FFFF0000</color>
                <width>4</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>
                      -74.65135184561255,40.34699603789065
                      -74.65134698312256 44.34698634192100
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
      .
      . more than 66,000 lines omitted
      .
</Folder>
```

I've written the XSLT to transform the XML into these KML Folders and the only thing left to do is get them under the same folder.

What I've been trying to do is move all of the items from the group with id='Route' into the group with id='Entryway.

In my xslt file is an apply-templates at the group nodes.

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ds:group">
        <xsl:sort select="ds:display_name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

This is picked up by the template match for each group.

```
<xsl:template match="ds:group">
```

At which point I'm lost.  I'll post my code but it is only going to confuse and depress you.

```
<xsl:template match="ds:group">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(ds:id = 'Route') and not(ds:id = 'Entryway')">
            <Folder id="{ds:id}">
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ds:display_name"/>
                </name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ds:item">
                    <xsl:sort select="ds:name"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </Folder>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="ds:id = 'Entryway'">
            <Folder id='Accessible'>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ds:display_name"/>
                </name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ds:item">
                    <xsl:sort select="ds:name"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </Folder>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="ds:id = 'Route'">
            <!--  Copy all of current node to Entryway node -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't think I'm going about this the right way.  By the time the XSLT process gets to the group with id='Route' the KML Folder for Entryway has already been written.  I'm at a dead end.  Can I union two groups together based on the value of "id"? Conceptually the idea would be:  `<xsl:template match="ds:id='Route' | ds:id='Entryway'">`  But that doesn't even compile.

Can I copy all of the elements of the group (id='Route') to the group (id='Entryway') after the first group has been processed?

Thank you in advance for your time and attention.

George

Comment: It's not clear whether the output should be one folder containing two groups or many folders, one of which contains two groups and the rest one folder for each remaining group. I suggest you reduce your code to a [mcve].

Comment: The goal is to have each group transformed into a Folder except. for the groups with id = 'Entryway' and 'Route'.  Those two groups should be in the same Folder with id = 'Accessible'.  Thank you for suggesting a minimal reproducible example.  I'll probably do that if nobody has a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to "step" in at the `document` level and do e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="ds:document">
  <Folder id='Accessible'>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ds:group[ds:id = 'Entryway' or ds:id = 'Route']"/>
  </Folder>
  <!-- process other ds:group here as well e.g. 
       <xsl:apply-templates select="ds:group[not(ds:id = 'Entryway' or ds:id = 'Route')]"/>
  -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Martin,
This was exactly the clue that I needed.  I "stepped" up to the document level and selected on the groups that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:document">
    <Folders>
        <xsl:variable name="accessible" select="ns0:group[ns0:id='Entryway' or ns0:id ='Route']" />
        <xsl:if test="$accessible">
            <Folder id="Accessible">
                <name>Accessible Features</name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$accessible/ns0:item"/>
            </Folder>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:group[not(ns0:id='Entryway' or ns0:id ='Route')]"/>
    </Folders>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:group">
    <Folder id="{ns0:id}">
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="display_name"/>
        </name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:item"/>
    </Folder>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:item">
    <Placemark id="{ns0:id}">
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:name"/>
        </name>
        <!-- more here -->
    </Placemark>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This is very close to what I ended up with.  I wish I could give two answers credit for solving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/ds:document">
    <kml>
        <Document>
            <name>Campus Map</name>                
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ds:group[ds:id != 'Entryway' and ds:id != 'Route']">
                <xsl:sort select="ds:display_name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <Folder id='Accessible'>
                <name>Accessible Feature</name>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ds:group[ds:id = 'Entryway' or ds:id = 'Route']"/>
            </Folder>
        </Document>
    </kml>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="ds:group[ds:id = 'Entryway' or ds:id = 'Route']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ds:item"/>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="ds:group[ds:id != 'Entryway' and ds:id != 'Route']">
    <Folder id="{ds:id}">
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="ds:display_name"/>
        </name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ds:item">
            <xsl:sort select="ds:name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Folder>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is the code that I will put into production.  Based on Martin's suggestion to "step" up to the document level and select on the groups that I wanted to transform separately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).